# How to configure domain name in apache tomcat

Tags: java, linux, apache, web-services, tomcat

**I'm Using CentOS release 6.6 (Final)**

It's my doimain name [online.transferglobal.com](http://online.transferglobal.com)

when i type the url in browser it pointing to web server default web page

But here is my application link http://h2408361.stratoserver.net:8080/

how can i configure in httpd.conf please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable mod_proxy module in httpd.conf

   ```
   i.e uncomment line below line httpd.conf
   LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
   ```
2. Create Vhost with mod_proxy in httpd.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
   ServerAdmin admin@online.transferglobal.com
   ServerName online.transferglobal.com  
   ServerAlias online.transferglobal.com


   ProxyRequests Off  
   ProxyPreserveHost On  
   <Proxy *>  
      Order allow,deny  
      Allow from all  
   </Proxy>  


   ProxyPass /  http://h2408361.stratoserver.net:8080/  
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://h2408361.stratoserver.net:8080/


   ErrorLog logs/online.transferglobal.com-error_log  
   CustomLog logs/online.transferglobal.com-access_log common  

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. restart apache/httpd service

Comment: i followed your steps again it shows default plesk page. i enable plesk panel in my server . i think port 80 assigned for plesk.

Comment: please check http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/118537

Comment: please check http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/118537

Comment: i need one more help how can i apply ssl for my domain